# Programmatically set an IB object's Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

When using Interface Builder, a lot of the time I'd set the Class property to one of my custom classes. Say I have a UIView in the nib and I set the class to my `MyView` class.

That's all well and good, even when loading the nib programmatically.

But, is there a way to set the Class of a UI control when programmatically loading a nib? The reason being that I want to sometimes use the same nib created in IB, but have it associated with a different Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a proper way to achieve that programmatically.

You could create a naked UIView object in IB and give it a tag or assign it to an IBOutlet for its identification so taht you can access it programmatically in viewDidLoad.

In viewDidLoad you access it and fetch its frame and superview and probably background colour, alpha, hidden status etc, so that you can set all those values in IB. Then remove the UIView from its superview and nil the property (if any) or release the object respectively (depending on ARC or not). Then create the UI Element that you need, assign it to the property (if any) add it to the superview of the former UIView, set its frame and properties accordingly and go from there.

(There are ways in Obj-C to change an object's class after its instanciation, but I would not recommend doing that in this case, especially when your subclasses come with additional properties and ivars.)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation -- you've convinced me. While playing I decided to do some of the small things I originally tried with inheritance (and hence my question) by using a delegate in my UIView class. That feels better to me now and more Cocoa-like.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you create a UIView object on your UIViewController's class XIB file using Interface Builder and then you use the Custom Class tool in the Identity Inspector to associate the UIView with a class (The class is a UIView class containing the code for drawing on the UIView object.).  Then you have to use @property and @systhesize in your UIViewController class to hook the UIView (using the connections inspector) to your class.  This method is OK but in certain circumstances it has limitations.

You can get around all of this pragmatically.

Create the UIView class that will be used to draw on a UIView object.  In this class you create the context reference (CGContextRef) to give the drawing tools a context (where to draw) for such things as strings, lines, circles, etc. i.e.

```
CGContextRef gg = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

In the UIViewController class, in the .h file you need to import a reference to your UIView class.  Let's call it: DrawOnView

```
#import "DrawOnView.h"
```

Then in the brackets encompassing the @interface place this line:

```
UIView * draw;  // draw can be changed to any name that suits your needs
```

Then in the .m part of the class inside the viewDidLoad method you need to insert this code:

```
 // Make the size and location that suits your needs
 // You can change this on the go in your code as needed, such as if the
 // device orientation is changed.
 draw = [DrawOnView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectCreate(50, 50, 100, 200)];
 // You can change the background color of the view, if you like:
 [draw setBackGroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
 // Now add the view to your primary view
 [self.view addSubview:draw];
```

Now, in other parts of our program, you can call methods you have declared in the DrawOnView class and refresh (which calls the drawRect method, the primary entry point in your UIView class) by using this reference:

```
[(DrawOnView*) draw setNeedsDisplay];
```

This is very important.  Do not use:

```
[draw setNeedsDisplay];  // This will not work!
```

Let's say you have other methods defined in DrawOnView and want to call them.

Here's an example method (in the .h file):

```
-(BOOL) wasHotSpotHit: (CGPoint) p;
```

The actual method could look like this (in the .m file):

```
 -(BOOL) washHotSpotHit: (CGPont) p 
 {
   if(CGRectContainsPont(hotspot.frame, p))
   {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
 }
```

Use code like this:

```
 if([(DrawOnView*) draw testIfSpotHit:p])
 {
     // Do something for when user touches hot spot.
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using "object_setClass(id object, Class cls)" method of Objective c runtime. GoodLuck:)

Comment: You should explain what are the consequences and restrictions of this proposal. Isa swizzling is complex.

Comment: To use `object_setClass(id object, Class cls)` method you must use `#include <objc/runtime.h>`